# Jquery, Escaping url with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

trying to escape and html for appending in jquery with adding a dynamic variable that i am bringing in with ajax and I seem to not be able to get the escaping correct. Here is what I have -

```
$("<div><div class='presiImg' style='background: url(/\'/gleam\/public\/images\/itPrecedents\/" + keep.logo + "');'></div></div>").appendTo(".myDiv');
```

I am unsure how to escape this correctly so I can use the variable. Thanks.

Comment: I've never seen a url with a single quote in it.  What should the url be?

Comment: not clear. write ajax response also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple issues here:

1. You're escaping the forward slashes in your URL and that is not necessary
2. You are using inconsistent quotes in your `.appendTo()`

As a suggestion, when I append raw HTML using JS/jQuery I try to use the single-quote and the JavaScript quote, and then use the double-quotes in the HTML. For me it is just easier to see that way. Also, the single-quote in the CSS url is not required, and is perhaps confusing the matter.

Anyway, if you change your line to the following it will work:

```
$('<div><div class="presiImg" style="background: url(\'/gleam/public/images/itPrecedents/' + keep.logo + '\');"></div></div>').appendTo('.myDiv');
```

There is a runnable example below if you want to see it in action:

```js
$(function() {
  
  var keep = { logo : "test.jpg" };
  $('<div><div class="presiImg" style="background: url(\'/gleam/public/images/itPrecedents/' + keep.logo + '\');"></div></div>').appendTo('.myDiv');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("<div />",{ 
 "class":"presiImg",
 "style":"background: url(/gleam/public/images/itPrecedents/"+keep.logo+")"
}).appendTo(".myDiv");
```